# Returning data from one function to insert into another function using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, axios

I am trying to create a Map on my website using the Google Maps JavaScript API in my ASP.NET Core Razor Pages project. The user will enter an address, which will be saved as TempData and then inserted into the parameters for the Google Maps Geocoder API, which will then turn the address into coordinates. I want to, then, use these coordinates as parameters to the Google Maps Javascript API call.

I have a function called getLatitude and a function called getLongitude, as shown:

```
     function getLatitude() {
        searchedAddress = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(ViewData["searchString"]));
        axios.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json', {
            params: {
                address: searchedAddress,
                key: 'xxxxxx'
            }
        })
            .then(function (response) {
                var lat = response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;

                // This prints the correct value to the console.
                console.log(lat)
                
                // I want to return this value when I call the method.
                return lat;
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }

     function getLongitude() {
        searchedAddress = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(ViewData["searchString"]));
        axios.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json', {
            params: {
                address: searchedAddress,
                key: 'xxxxxx'
            }
        })
            .then(function (response) {
                var lng = response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
                
                // This prints the correct value to the console.
                console.log(lng);

                // I want to return this value when I call the method.
                return lng;     
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }
```

Then I have a function called initMap, which creates the map using the Google Maps JavaScript API:

```
    function initMap() {
        var latitude = getLatitude()
        var longitude = getLongitude()

        // This is where I need to input the getLatitude and getLongitude data
        const location = { lat: latitude, lng: longitude }

        var options = {
            zoom: 15,
            center: location
        }
        const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);
        const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: location,
            map: map,
        });
    }
```

How can I use the data that I am able to print to the console in my getLatitude and getLongitude functions and put it into the initMap function location variable?

Answer (score 0):

Axios provides asynchronous functions, and the latitude and longitude vars initialize as empty because initMap() has already finished running before the data is returned. console.log() prints the location data after axios.get() successfully returns the data but too late for initData().

I suggest you get the (lat, lon) with axios and run initMap() inside the then to ensure your data has arrived before moving on.

**WARNING UNTESTED**

Maybe something like this.

```js
function getLatLong() {
  searchedAddress = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(ViewData["searchString"]));
  axios.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json', {
    params: {
      address: searchedAddress,
      key: 'xxxxxx'
    }
  })
    .then(function (response) {
      var lng = response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
      var lat = response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;

      // This prints the correct value to the console.
      console.log(lat, lng);

      // This is where I need to input the getLatitude and getLongitude data
      const location = { lat: latitude, lng: longitude }

      var options = {
        zoom: 15,
        center: location
      }
      const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);
      const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        map: map,
      })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

```
  async function getLatitude() {
    searchedAddress = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(ViewData["searchString"]));
    const response = await axios.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json', {
        params: {
            address: searchedAddress,
            key: 'xxxxxx'
        }
    });

    let lat = response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;       
    return lat;
}

   async function getLongitude() {
    searchedAddress = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(ViewData["searchString"]));
    const response = await axios.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json', {
        params: {
            address: searchedAddress,
            key: 'xxxxxx'
        }
    });
    let lng = response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
    return lng;
}
```

Your caller function `initMap()`

```
    async function initMap() {
    let latitude = await getLatitude()
    let longitude = await getLongitude()

    const location = { lat: latitude, lng: longitude }

    var options = {
        zoom: 15,
        center: location
    }
    const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);
    const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        map: map,
    });
}
```